# Feature Detection from an image using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, matlab-cvst

i wanted to know that is there any algorithm that can be used for efficient feature detection from an image, i am currently using SIFT algorithm in MATLAB , but the results aren't good! So if someone could please suggest me a better algo that can make my work easier in MATLAB .

Comment: In my experience of using e.g. Machine Learning techniques, almost every time I use an established algorithm and the results aren't good, it is because there is something wrong with my code - not the algorithm. If you're sure that you're doing everything right, then explain what kind of data you have - which algorithm is best depends entirely on what kind of problem you have.

Comment: so what about SURF and FAST alrorithm? The results of all of these algorithms heavily depend on the image itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest for using SURF algorithm, it's better and faster, and i think it has been implemented in MATLAB

Comment: i just implemented the SURF algo in Matlab, the only issue is that the two images should have the same dimensions, but in my case i have different dimension images and it gives error at the time of plotting `% Show both images
  I = zeros([size(I1,1) size(I1,2)*2 size(I1,3)]);
  I(:,1:size(I1,2),:)=I1; I(:,size(I1,2)+1:size(I1,2)+size(I2,2),:)=I2;
  figure, imshow(I/255); hold on;
`, so is there something i can do to resolve it?

Comment: error is  ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> example2 at 27
  I(:,1:size(I1,2),:)=I1; I(:,size(I1,2)+1:size(I1,2)+size(I2,2),:)=I2;

Comment: @Richante my task is to compare two images and tell whether the object inside both the images match with each other or not

Comment: i have an idea, but i can't imagine the result yet, i think you should make the images size equal, but of course for the smaller image there will be empty space. And you need to fill the empty space with color that not in your image or with color that appear in smallest count, maybe you can use color histogram or something like that